# where is flex mobile application app-storagedirectory in android tablet

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, tablet, android, flex-mobile

I created a mobile/tablet application in flex, using flex mobile application in Flex4 using SDK4.1. In application, there is some data which i copy from application directory to app-storage directory. It is copied successfully and working fine. Now i want to know where i can find the location of app-storage directory of that application. When i trace app-storage directory path, it is showing "data/data/air.applicationname/local store/", so where it is:
- in SD card
- in phone memory

Please give me an idea to find out the application storage physical location. Any web link or code sample would be appreciated.

Comment: why some one put negative mark for that question? Can anybody explain the reason?

Comment: If I had to guess you got downvoted because your question is hard to read due to grammar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's in the internal phone storage

folder

`"/data/app/air.applicationname/local store"`

`data/app` is the default folder of non system / manually installed application on android

`air.applicationname` is the name of your application
`local store` is a folder created by flex to store the datas...

You can't see/use this folder manually or using a file explorer without rooting your device... the only way to access this folder without rooting is through the application itself...

hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks Marcx for response. One question i have, If i move data to SD Card, then can it possible to access directory? Or where it will be on SD Card?

Comment: yes you can! you can save wherever you want in the SD Card :)

Comment: Hi Marcx, sorry for delaying response. Please give me a favor, can you please share a link or a code sample to write application data in SD card in flex mobile application for android.

Comment: instead of using `File.applicationStorageDirectory` use `File.desktopDirectory` (desktopDirectory on android is always the SD Card)

Comment: Hi Marcx, i try to use File.desktopDirectory but it is not pointing to SD card, it is pointing to tablet memory. Please update, how can i access SD card data in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I have been debugging my app on an `Android` device and my db file's parent `nativePath` is on:

```
/data/data/air.com.package.of.project/com.package.of.project/Local Store/
```